# ADT to Android Studio UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, adt

So, I'm trying to migrate my Eclipse ADT project into Android Studio. I am using the appcompat_v7 project as a library project in eclipse. I followed the instructions on the Android Development site, but I am still receiving this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task :PaWPal:dexDebug.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/godswood/Desktop/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/dex/debug /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/classes/debug /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v13-7e8441dbe126e0c6ef27b0769fe1a7b51230f497.jar /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v4-435683bcc81493f96c2a6911d0f2132f9185a3c8.jar /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v7-appcompat-ce23957a305e187b582a49f3d7389771481d29a0.jar /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-0df1e7b55f7a1cf804d7c324e4d8e5350156c424.jar /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/commons-lang3-3.3.2-414f8e20d93f4cd78deef61257feb20e410dc32e.jar /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/joda-time-2.3-e2f8ddd39c18a5b5f810a870e98c34e25539e6e9.jar /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/joda-time-2.3-javadoc-2b8389d156c40d0540abb1e521b4be4ba90b89b7.jar /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/joda-time-2.3-sources-ee3d5e4a6e2aceeeee41f9ab558b6a1430285670.jar /Users/godswood/Desktop/pawpal/PaWPal/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/Parse-1.5.1-b7ce0ef98d2f79d618c5421f63a4845519bd4ced.jar
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

And my Gradle File looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':appcompat_v7')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear them. I know there are a lot of similar questions on here, but none of the solutions worked for me (sad face).

Comment: That dex error comes from referencing a jar/library multiple times. Probably an scenario like this: project A references project B and the support library, while project B also references the Support library. Haven't checked your question thoroughly but wanted to give my 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, you don't need to include the appcompat library as a library project the way you do in Eclipse. Instead, add this to the `dependencies` block of your ***module***'s build file:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XXXX.+'
```

where `XXXX` is your `compileSdkVersion`.

Also, I suspect you have a copy of the v4 support library jar in your libs folder (which where you're getting its classes multiple-defined). If you include the appcompat lib as you do above, you don't need to include support-v4 at all; appcompat depends on it, and the build system will do the right thing. So go ahead and remove that jar from your libs folder.

Comment: Maybe because I don't know what you mean by my module's build file, but this didn't quite seem to work. Deleting the jar caused a lot of errors, so I put it back.